# Stopping multiple database access when user refreshes browser

Tags: java, database

Say we have a database query that takes 20seconds to run (the user runs it by clicking a button on HTML page in a browser).
The user gets impatient and only after 10seconds he refreshes his browser, only to run a new query.

How do I stop the first running database query (or prevent the second one from running)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If this is using Ajax, disable the
  button that starts the query until
  after the query is finished.
- When the use makes the request, set a
  flag in the user session, and then
  start the query on a separate thread.
  If they try to submit it again, check
  the flag, and simply ignore the
  request. When the query finishes,
  reset the flag. While the query is
  running, the browser can poll the
  server waiting for the results.

Answer (score 3):

First step would be to optimize that query, 20 seconds is way too long for most queries. Users won't generally tolerate that kind of poor performance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but you can store the time he last filed the query in his session. If the same user file another query with 20 secs, just ignore it.

It's not really a brute force way though.